# Things you'll find in me; numerous dark knights with the Earl of Erroll... What am I?

Tags: riddle

**Things you might find in me...**

Numerous dark knights with the Earl of Erroll.

A ham-fisted Napoleon of 1945.

Sometimes converted but often cold.

Plenty of mice and other things live.

**What am I?**

*I'll add more clues if it's a bit too cryptic! :)*

EDIT:

It's quite a cryptic one, all words are clues. :)

Comment: The [tag:cryptic-clues] tag is for [cryptic crossword](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptic_crossword)-style clues specifically. If your clues are not in this format, please remove the tag.

Comment: Removed tag as requested.

Comment: @Andrew, based on your 'EDIT', is [tag:steganography] maybe appropriate? Just guessing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it a...

> barn?

The dark knights and Lord of Erroll are

> Bats and Hay

A ham-fisted Napoleon is

> A reference to Animal Farm, published in 1945.

Sometimes converted, often cold

> Barns are sometimes converted to serve other purposes, and are often not very well insulated, which would make them cold in winter (at least in my geographic location)

Plenty of mice and other things live

> In barns.

Comment: You got it! Although the dark knights was a reference to Christian Bale as he played Batman in the Dark Knight trilogy. And the reference was Bale as in bales of hay but bats works too! :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you a

> Lair?

Numerous dark knights with the Earl of Erroll.

> Bat cave/lair for the Dark Knight

A ham-fisted Napoleon of 1945.

> Wolf's lair

Sometimes converted but often cold.

> Lair's are cold and sometimes converted, e.g. man cave.

Plenty of mice and other things live.

> Mice live underground in a lair or subterranean.

Comment: Nice guess but afraid not.